# Order Statistics Question about largest and second largest

Tags: probability, order-statistics

I'm doing this problem from Carol Ash's *The Probability Tutoring Book*

> Let $X_1, X_2, ... , X_7$ be iid and have common density $f(x)$ and common distribution $F(x)$. Find the probability that the largest is less than 9 and the second largest is less than 5

My attempt:

We want $P(\max \leq 9 \cap \text{2nd largest} \leq 5)$

$$P(\max \leq 9 \cap \text{2nd largest} \leq 5) = 7P(\text{max} \leq 9 )P(\text{2nd largest} \leq 5)^6 \\= 7F(9)F(5)^6$$

My reasoning:

The $7$ comes from choosing 1 of the 7 to be the max

The first equality comes from independence and the second comes from the definition of the CDF.

However according to the back of the book the answer is $$F(5)^7 + 7(F(9) - F(5))(F(5))^6$$

Thir answer makes sense to me, but I don't know why my answer is wrong(logically it makes sense to me). The way their answer works (I believe) is they did

$$P(\text{all} \leq 5) + P(\text{1 X between 5 and 9 while the rest are less than 5}) $$

Where is my reasoning wrong?  I choose one X to be anything less than $9$ and the others are less than $5$

Comment: If you know the largest is less than 9, the conditional probability of the second largest being less than five changes, and it looks like you assumed those are independent events (i.e., multiplied together).  The CDFs of order stats are actually a Markov chain, not independent.

Comment: In the problem statement, we're given that all the $X_i$'s are iid, does this mean something different for order statistics?

Comment: The sample is iid, but the order stats are not independent of one another. If the largest is less than 9, the second largest cannot be greater than 9. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic#The_joint_distribution_of_the_order_statistics_of_an_absolutely_continuous_distribution

Comment: Thus to make use of the iid property, you must express the event in terms of *arbitrary samples* rather than *ordered statistics*.  You can not just pick a special *one* to be less than 9 and the *others* to be less than 5.  When all samples are below 5, none are special.  You have to express it as: $${\text{all seven are at most 5, or}\\\text{one among the seven is between 5 and 9 while the remaining six are at most 5}}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The way their answer works (I believe) is they did
>
> $$P(\text{all} \leq 5) + P(\text{1 X between 5 and 9 while the rest are less than 5}) $$

That's the intuitive approach.  It matches the integration result:

$$\begin{align}f_{\small X_{(6)},X_{(7)}}(y,z) &= \dfrac{7!}{5!} F(y)^5 f(y) f(z)\\[4ex] F_{\small X_{(6)},X_{(7)}}(y,z)&=\dfrac {7!}{5!}\int_{-\infty}^{5}\int_y^9 F(y)^5f(y)f(z)\mathrm d z\mathrm d y\\&=42\int_{-\infty}^5 F(y)^5f(y)(F(9)-F(y))\mathrm d y\\&=42\int_0^{F(5)} x^5 (F(9)-x)\mathrm d x&&{x=F(y)\\ \mathrm d x=f(y)\mathrm d y}\\&=\int_0^{F(5)} 7\cdot 6 x^5 F(9)- 6\cdot 7x ^6~\mathrm d x\\[1ex] &= 7 F(5)^6 F(9)-6F(5)^7 \\[3ex]&= F(5)^7 -7(F(9)-F(5))F(5)^6\end{align}$$

---

> I choose one X to be anything less than 9 and the others are less than 5.

Which are "the others" when they are in the same category?

The constants in the expression derive from counting *distinct* arrangements.  When the one you choose is less than 5 it becomes indistinguishable from the other six described that way.  So you must partition the events between "all are birds of a feather" and "one stands out from the crowd" to properly account for this.

$$P\left(\bigcap_{i}\{X_i \leqslant 5\}\right) + P\left(\bigcup_j \left(\{5<X_j\leqslant 9\}\cap\bigcap_{i\neq j}\{X_i\leqslant 5\}\right)\right)\\{\huge=}\\ \mathsf P(X_1\leqslant 5)^7+ 7\mathsf P(5<X_1\leqslant 9)\mathsf P(X_2\leqslant 5)^6\\{\huge=}\\ F(5)^7-7\,(F(9)-F(5))\,F(5)^6 $$